# Running a Ruby class from a Shoes Edit Line

Tags: ruby, shoes

Hello All,

I have finished writing up a Ruby class to complete exactly what it is supposed to, but since it is Ruby, I have been running it through my terminal and I need this to be more user-friendly (i.e. have a GUI). So I googled this and came across Shoes, which seems to be a nice Ruby GUI toolkit, and exactly what I am looking for. However, despite my googling I can't seem to figure out how to use a Shoes GUI edit line to send an argument to the class I made. Here is the edit line

`Shoes.app do 
    background white
    para "Application Name"
    stack(margin: 12) do
      para "Message"
      flow do
        edit_line
        button "Enter"
      end
    end
end`

In short, is there some way to do a gets.chomp (or literally anything else that is similar) with this and set it equal to an instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Just assign the elements you want to keep track of to instance variables, and pass a block to the button (the block gets executed when the button is clicked). Try this:

```
Shoes.app do 
  background white
  para "Application Name"
  stack(margin: 12) do
    @message = para "Message"
    flow do
      @edit_line = edit_line
      button "Enter" do
        @message.text = @edit_line.text
      end
    end
  end
end
```